# Laravel Blade Templates Section Repeated / cache error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, templating, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-blade

I am looking to Bootstrap my site and as such, have put common twitter bootstrap components into blade templates.

sidebar.blade.php

```
@include('panel1')
@include('panel2')
```

panelTemplate.blade.php

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">   
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-title">
            @yield('title')
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
            @yield('body')
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
            @yield('footer')
    </div>
</div>
```

This way, every time I wish to use a panel, then I can use `@extends('panelTemplate')`.

panel1.blade.php

```
@extends('panelTemplate')
@section('title')
 title panel 1
@stop

@section('body')
 body panel 1
@stop

@section('footer')
 footer panel 1
@stop
```

panel2.blade.php

```
@extends('panelTemplate')
@section('title')
 title panel 2
@stop

@section('body')
 body panel 2
@stop

@section('footer')
 footer panel 2
@stop
```

The problem that I am facing is that instead of showing the contents of `panel1.blade.php`, then the contents of `panel2.blade.php` as declared in `sidebar.blade.php` the contents of `panel1.blade.php` is being repeated (shown twice).

Is Blade caching the request which is why panel1 is being repeated twice? Is there a way to override this behaviour or am I using the blade templating engine in a way which it was never intended?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this by [overwriting](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates#other-blade-control-structures) the sections.. try what you have already, but with these two updated sub-views:

**panel1.blade.php**

```
@extends('panelTemplate')

@section('title')
 title panel 1
@overwrite

@section('body')
 body panel 1
@overwrite

@section('footer')
 footer panel 1
@overwrite
```

**panel2.blade.php**

```
@extends('panelTemplate')

@section('title')
 title panel 2
@overwrite

@section('body')
 body panel 2
@overwrite

@section('footer')
 footer panel 2
@overwrite
```

It's tested and working here, though I'm not sure it's the intended use of `@overwrite`, so test thoroughly!

Comment: Excellent answer! Unfortunately your link is broken and I am unable to find anything about `@overwrite` in the docs. Glad the answer is here!

Comment: @samrap - there you go, link corrected :) - It was in version 4.2, you'll have to check for v5 of Laravel..

Comment: I don't think the same method exists in version 5 of Laravel... you'll have to check how best to achieve what you need to do - best place to start is here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade

Comment: I'm using 5.1 and this method works fine, it's just strange that it is not in the docs. Perhaps it's deprecated?