# Included blade template repeating in each foreach loop iteration

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

I'm using Blade templating with Laravel and I'm trying to use a `@foreach` loop to display notifications. The problem is that if I have say 10 notifications, the first notification is repeated 10 times.

The code to output each notification:

```
@foreach ( Auth::user()->unreadNotifications as $notification )

    {{ $notification->type->web_template }}
    {{ $notification->id }}
    @include($notification->type->web_template)

@endforeach
```

`web_template` will output a path to the template: `notifications.web.user_alert`

For each iteration of the loop the `{{ $notification->type->web_template }}` and `{{ $notification->id }}` will output what they're supposed to but `@include($notification->type->web_template)` will only output the first notification each time.

So the output will look like:

---

*156 notification.web.new_message*

**You have a new message from Joe.**

---

*154 notification.web.user_alert*

**You have a new message from Joe.**

---

*145 notification.web.new_like*

**You have a new message from Joe.**

---

I think it's some sort of cache issue maybe, but I couldn't find anyone with the same problem.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE: Adding some code**

Example notification view:

```
@extends('layouts.notification-wrapper')

@section('url', url('jobs/'.$notification->job_id.'#highlight'.$notification->bid_id))

@section('image', '/assets/img/no-photo.jpg')

@section('header', $notification->collector->firstname . ' ' . $notification->collector->secondname)

@section('description')
has placed a bid of €{{ number_format($notification->bid()->withTrashed()->first()->amount,0) }} on your job.
@stop
```

Notification wrapper:

```
<li @if(!$notification->read) 
    class="unread" 
    @endif>
    <a href="@yield('url')" data-id="{{ $notification->id }}">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <img src="@yield('image')" class="img-circle" alt="user image">
        </div>
        <h4>
            @yield('header')
            <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> {{ $notification->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</small>
        </h4>
        <p> @yield('description')</p>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you pass the notification to the include? `@include($notification->type->web_template, ['notification' => $notification])`

Comment: I changed it but it's still repeating the same template.

Comment: What is the view look like? Please put it in the question.

Comment: Added example view and it's wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for help but found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659615/laravel-blade-templates-section-repeated-cache-error

Comment: This seems to be a bug in Laravel. Don't have the time to report it now. Just leaving this comment for future reference. A good workaround is to use Components and Slots. See it here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#components-and-slots

Answer (score 5):

Answering my own question!

Found this: [Laravel Blade Templates Section Repeated / cache error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659615/laravel-blade-templates-section-repeated-cache-error)

Basically whatever way it works I need to overwrite my sections when looping and using `@yield`... I think. So I need to replace `@stop` with `@overwrite` in my views.